# Accessing named regex capture groups in multiple matches

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a single line of text which may contain 1 or more matches.  I am using named capture groups since I am continuously changing things around, and this makes it easier.

String:

```
blah blah blah dasf{{optionA:B4}}t estsdf{{optionB:B4}}sadf{{optionB:B4}}sadf13
```

Pattern:

```
(?<choice>\{\{(?<c>optionA|optionB):(?<d>[A-Z]\d{1,2})\}\})
```

Every example I can find online which deals with this type of structure doesn't use named capture groups, and I haven't been able to puzzle it together myself.

In my example scenario, there are 3 matches, and for each match, I want to be able to access the **content** of the 'choice', 'c' and 'd' capture groups.

Can someone show me a simple example of how to do this?

Comment: Do you really mean backreferences? Or captures? Do you want to refer to the groups **within** the regex or **after** execution of the regex?

Comment: after execution, I basically need to know .Value for all these matches.

Comment: Alright, that is called capturing. Backreferences usually only refer to the things inside the regex or sometimes inside the replacement string (what Tim Pietzker showed in his answer)

Answer (score 4):

To access the contents of named capturing groups after a match, you need to use a regex object:

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("(?<quote>['""])(?<text>.*?)\k<quote>")
Result = RegexObj.Match(Subject).Groups("text").Value
```

Now `Result` will contain the contents of the `(?<text>...)` capturing group.

For multiple matches, you can iterate over the results, calling `.NextMatch()` until the last match has been found:

```
Dim ResultList As StringCollection = New StringCollection()
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("(?<quote>['""])(?<text>.*?)\k<quote>")
Dim Result As Match = RegexObj.Match(Subject)
While MatchResult.Success
    ResultList.Add(Result.Groups("text").Value)
    Result = Result.NextMatch()
End While
```

---

The original answer to the question (which had been about backreferences, not capturing groups):

There are two situations where you can use backreferences:

- To refer to a backreference within the same regex, use `\k<groupname>`.
- To insert the text matched by a named group in the replacement text, use `${groupname}`.

For example,

```
res = Regex.Replace(subject, "(?<quote>['""])(?<text>.*?)\k<quote>", "*${text}*")
```

will change

```
This is a "quoted text" and 'so is this'!
```

into

```
This is a *quoted text* and *so is this*!
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I am not understanding how it answers my question, as I don't see how it would allow me to access these values within VB .NET code.

Comment: @se_dude: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. Is this better?

Comment: That's about as far as I have gotten.  The issue is that I am dealing with multiple matches, and each match has 3 named groups.

I really do appreciate your help!

Comment: While there were some issues with the code, it did set me on the right track, so thank you VERY much for taking the time to help me :)  I would give you a vote, but can't vote yet.

I was using MatchCollections before, which made things really complicated, while your method was a lot easier, and actually worked.

Also learned something new (StringCollection) :)